# Why subscribe method is working twice?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, subscribe

I'm subscribe firebase list in ionic2 project.

This is my function inside the service:

```
  getLastOrderBeta() {
    return this.db.list(`Ring/${localStorage.getItem('localstorage')}`, {
        query: {
          equalTo: false,
          orderByChild: 'status',
          limitToLast: 2,
        }
      })
      .map((orders: any) => {
        return orders.map((order: any) => {
          order.userInfo = this.getProfile(order.userid);
          return order;
        });
      });
  }
```

This is my subscribe:

```
  subscribeOrder(){
    this.orderList = this.orderProvider.getLastOrderBeta();
    this.orderList.subscribe((s: any) => {
      this.selectedOrder = "";
      console.log(this.playSound,"outside the if");
      if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.playSound && s.length) {
          console.log(this.playSound,"inside the if");
          this.audioProvider.playRingTone();
      }
      this.playSound = true;
    });
  }
```

> The *subscribeOrder()* logs showed twice.

this is my html code:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="orderList | async as orders">
    <span *ngFor="let order of orders?.slice().reverse(); let first = first; let last = last">
      <ng-container *ngIf="first && !selectedOrder" [ngTemplateOutlet]="orderView" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{order:order,selected:false}"></ng-container>
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="last && (last !== first) ? beforeLastOrder : waiting" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{order:order}"></ng-container>
    </span>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!orders.length">
      <ion-fab bottom left>
        <button (click)="logOut()" ion-fab mini>
          <ion-icon name="power"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button (click)="openSettings()" ion-fab mini>
          <ion-icon name="wifi"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-fab>
      <span *ngIf="batterPercentage" class="battery">{{batterPercentage}}%</span>
      <img *ngIf="!selectedOrder" class="rnb-img-waiting" src="assets/logo.png">
      <ion-item (click)="showModal()" class="ion-footer">
        <span class="no-orders">Previous Orders</span>
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Any explanation  for this duplication an how can i solved.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure there are no other subscriptions or async pipes in the app?

Comment: I used | async pipe inside the html file of course

Comment: Async pipe in Angular manages the subscription of your Observables. So if you are using it you don't need to call subscribe in your component.

Comment: I disabled the async pipe from my component and same result,,,

Comment: if I need to run a piece of code inside a subscribe method.. how can I run it using async pipe,, can u explain please ?

Comment: can you post a snippet from your html?

Comment: Ok I will edit my question  to add the html code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166085/discussion-between-khaled-ramadan-and-boris-lobanov).

Answer (score 2):

For your case, I'm guessing there are two solutions:

1. Don't use async pipe at all, just save the data from firebase in subscribe and feed it to the template:

   ```
    subscribeOrder(){
       this.orderList = this.orderProvider.getLastOrderBeta();
       this.orderList.subscribe((s: any) => {
         this.selectedOrder = "";
         console.log(this.playSound,"outside the if");
         if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.playSound && s.length) {
             console.log(this.playSound,"inside the if");
             this.audioProvider.playRingTone();
         }
         this.playSound = true;
         this.orders = s;
       });
     }
   ```

Then in your template:

2. Use async pipe but replace the subscribe in your component with a `do` operator if you need a side effect:

   ```
   subscribeOrder(){
       this.orderList = this.orderProvider.getLastOrderBeta()
           .do((s: any) => {
             this.selectedOrder = "";
             console.log(this.playSound,"outside the if");
             if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.playSound && s.length) {
                 console.log(this.playSound,"inside the if");
                 this.audioProvider.playRingTone();
             }
             this.playSound = true;
             this.orders = s;
           });
         }
   ```

Comment: `.do` not work once you subscribe to it so same thing.

Comment: ofCourse the do operator is better than my method (subscribe) thanks for remember me it.
But still I have duplication

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

After debugging I found the problem was from the *Angularfire2* query and exactly from the *limitToLast*.

So I disabled the *limitToLast*. And I created a code have the same role.

To became:

```
return this.db.list(`Ring/${localStorage.getItem('localstorage')}`, {
    query: {
      equalTo: false,
      orderByChild: 'status'
    }
  })
  .map((orders:any)=>{return orders.slice(-2)})
  .map((orders: any) => {
    return orders.map((order: any) => {
      order.userInfo = this.getProfile(order.userid);
      return order;
    });
  })  as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

and that is work properly.

Thanks.